# Add a variable in a .env file in python

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I have a .env file in my application and Im trying to run a script in docker. When docker reaches the `entrypoint.sh` it runs
`python manage.py runscript tryouts` getting a count and then it goes like this (jwt_token is generated earlier in the script):

```
ChirpStackURL = os.environ['CHIRPSTACK']

def checkNetworks(jwt_token):
    url = ChirpStackURL + '/api/network-servers?limit=10'
    res = requests.get(url, headers = {"Authorization": jwt_token})
    count = res.json()['totalCount']
    if count == '1' :
        return res.json()['result'][0]['id']
    else: 
        return False
```

and then on my function i want to add the result as an enviromental variable so i can access it later on new requests.

```
    networkServerID = checkNetworks(jwt_token)
    if not networkServerID:
        print('success')
    else:
      'export to .env file'
      'NETWORK_ID = networkServerID'

sample = os.environ['NETWORK_ID']
```

How do i do that ?

Comment: The `.env` file won't be automatically re-read, so trying to write into it doesn't do you any good. What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: The script runs on deployment and i want to save that variable to use it later on django signals in a different time when new users are created

Comment: Ah, right, this happens before your server runs. In that case, there's a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An envfile is just a text file with `key=value` lines, so append the new variable into it:

```
with open("path/to/my/.env", "a") as envfile:
    envfile.write(f"NETWORK_ID = {networkServerId}\n")
```

Comment: great thank you that worked like a charm . And a 2nd question if you dont mind. In case there is already saved a NETWORK_ID, how do i edit that one without creating a second NETWORK_ID below it ? I mean just put the value in the already existing NETWORK_ID

Comment: It shouldn't matter – an envfile parser would likely use the last value found in the file.